# How to make the whole Card component clickable in Material UI using React JS?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-design, material-ui

Im using [Material UI Next](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/cards/) in a React project. I have the Card component which has an image(Card Media) and text(Card Text) inside it. I also have a button underneath the text. My question is..how to make the whole card clickable? ie. Whether a user presses on the card text, or the card image or the button, it should trigger the onClick event which I call on the button.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

> **Update for v3 — 29 of August 2018**
>
> A specific [*CardActionArea* component](https://material-ui.com/api/card-action-area/) has been added to cover specifically this case in **version 3.0.0 of Material UI**.
>
> Please use the following solution only if you are stuck with v1.

What you probably want to achieve is a [**Card Action** (see specification)](https://material.io/guidelines/components/cards.html#cards-actions) on the top part of the card.

The Material Components for Web library has this as its [first usage example for the Card Component](https://material-components-web.appspot.com/card.html).

You can easily reproduce that exact behaviour by composing MUI `Card*` components with the mighty `ButtonBase` component. ***A running example can be found [here on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/q9wnzv7684): https://codesandbox.io/s/q9wnzv7684***.

The relevant code is this:

```
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import CardMedia from '@material-ui/core/CardMedia';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import ButtonBase from '@material-ui/core/ButtonBase';

const styles = {
  cardAction: {
    display: 'block',
    textAlign: 'initial'
  }
}

function MyCard(props) {
  return (
    <Card>
      <ButtonBase
          className={props.classes.cardAction}
          onClick={event => { ... }}
      >
        <CardMedia ... />
        <CardContent>...</CardContent>
      </ButtonBase>
    </Card>
  );
}

export default withStyles(styles)(MyCard)
```

Also I **strongly suggest** to keep the `CardActions` component outside of the `ButtonBase`.

Comment: This worked, although I found that I usually needed to add `width: 100%; height: 100%` to both the ButtonBase and the CardContent.

Comment: This seems to be overriding the CSS for the text elements inside CardContent

Answer (score 55):

With Material UI 4.9.10, this works.

```
<Card>
    <CardActionArea href="https://google.com">
        <CardContent>
            <Typography>Click me!</Typography>
        </CardContent>
    </CardActionArea>
</Card>
```

If you're using react router, this also works.

```
<Card>
    <CardActionArea component={RouterLink} to="/questions">
        <CardContent>
            <Typography>Click me!</Typography>
        </CardContent>
    </CardActionArea>
</Card>
```

Comment: Next to href, you can also add `target="_blank"` to CardActionArea

Comment: fantastic answer!

Comment: Great, `href` attribute on `CardActionArea` automatically converts it to an anchor tag too

Comment: Does anyone know which Typescript interface does the `href`, `component` & `to` props fall under? I'm trying add typing info to my code but `Partial<CardActionAreaProps>` don't work

Answer (score 17):

We can also use Link tag to make the whole Card component clickable and for navigation

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
function myCard() {
  return (
    <Link to={'/give_your_path'}>
     <Card>
      <Card text="This is text"/>
     </Card>
    </Link>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 13):

You could add an `onClick={clickFunction}` to the containing div of the card that links to the same function as the button.

Comment: Quick and easy, but probably not as pretty as some of the other solutions. Worked for what I needed.

Answer (score 10):

Here is the solution that worked for us, thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50444524/192092

```
import { Link as RouterLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link'

<Link underline='none' component={RouterLink} to='/your-target-path'>
  <Card>
    <CardActionArea>
      ...
    </CardActionArea>
  </Card>
</Link>
```

Comment: after doing some research, I found that <CardActionArea> can be used like the <ButtonBase> and has better visual feedback 

Answer (score 7):

Just wrap the whole thing in the Material CardActionArea component. Everything inside of it will be clickable.

```
<CardActionArea>
   <CardMedia>
   .......Image Stuff
   </CardMedia>
   <CardContent>
   .......Content
   </CardContent>
</CardActionArea>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using NextJS for routing, these two approaches worked for me.

1. Wrap the `<CardActionArea>` with a (NextJS) `<Link>` component:

```
import Link from 'next/link'

<Card>
  <Link href='/your-target-path' passHref>
    <CardActionArea>
      ...
    </CardActionArea>
  </Link>
</Card>
```

2. Use the effect `useRouter` to push the route on click:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

const router = useRouter()

<Card>
  <CardActionArea onClick={() => {router.push('/your-target-path')}}>
    ...
  </CardActionArea>
</Card>
```

Note that with this second approach, your browser won't recognize the URL, i.e., the activity bar (that appears on hover) won't be populated.

Answer (score 2):

In MUI 5.0 itcan be done by CardActionArea component

```
  export default function ActionAreaCard() {
    return (
     <Card sx={{ maxWidth: 345 }}>
      <CardActionArea>
        <CardMedia
          component="img"
          height="140"
          image="/static/images/cards/contemplative-reptile.jpg"
          alt="green iguana"
        />
        <CardContent>
          <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="div">
            Lizard
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="body2" color="text.secondary">
            Lizards are a widespread group of squamate reptiles, with over 6,000
            species, ranging across all continents except Antarctica
          </Typography>
        </CardContent>
      </CardActionArea>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use onClick event like this.

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  card: {
    cursor: "pointer",
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
  },
}));

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const clickMe = (event) => {
    console.log(event);
  }

  return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <Card className={classes.card} onClick={(event) => 
          {clickMe(event)}}>          
          <CardContent>
            <h4>test</h4>
          </CardContent>
          <CardActions>
            <Button size="small">Learn More</Button>
          </CardActions>
        </Card>
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

In MUI5:

Put the card in a `<Box />` then make the card an `<a>` tag component.

```
<Box component='a' href='/dashboard' sx={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}>
    <Card sx={{ height: '200px', cursor: 'pointer'}}>
        <CardContent>
           //CardContent
        </CardContent>
    </Card>
</Box>
```

Add styles like:

- Remove text Decoration since you have added `<a>` tag
- Give your card the preferred height
- Change the cursor to pointer on hover over the card

Answer (score -1):

Just add onPress props in your card

```
 <Card
                          onPress = {() => {console.log('onclick')}}
                          style={styles.item}
                          status="basic"
                          header={(headerProps) =>
                            this.renderItemHeader(headerProps, item)
                          }>
                          <Text>{item.description}</Text>
                        </Card>
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes