# Background images for dynamically rendered components not appearing on first render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, next.js, server-side-rendering

**EDIT:** I fixed this by dynamically importing the `<Card>` component inside of the Home function:

```
 const Card = dynamic(() => import("@material-ui/core/Card"), {
    loading: () => <div>Loading...</div>,
  });
```

---

For some reason, when  I dynamically render Material UI cards with background images (`<CardMedia>` component), the images do not appear on the first render. When I refresh the page, they also do not show.

However, when the page is rebuilt via `npm run dev` (after a file is modified and saved) the images appear only to disappear when the page is refreshed again!

If I use the source in as an `<img>`, they appear on first render and subsequent refreshes. So it has to be something either to do with Material UI or SSR of background images.

Has anyone got an idea?

PS. It has nothing to do with Apollo, I am using data imported from a JSON file in my directory.

```
import Layout from "../components/Layout";
import Head from "next/head";
import Link from "next/link";
import items from "../seeds";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { withApollo } from "../lib/apollo";
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/react-hooks";

//GQL
import gql from "graphql-tag";

//CARD IMPORTS
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardActionArea from "@material-ui/core/CardActionArea";
import CardActions from "@material-ui/core/CardActions";
import CardContent from "@material-ui/core/CardContent";
import CardMedia from "@material-ui/core/CardMedia";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

//CARD STYLES
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  card: {
    maxWidth: "100%",
    width: 270,
    margin: "1rem",
    textAlign: "center",
  },
  media: {
    height: 0,
    paddingTop: "56.25%",
  },
});

const HELLO_QUERY = gql`
  query HelloQuery {
    sayHello
  }
`;

function Home() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const MAX_LENGTH = 125;

  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(HELLO_QUERY);

  if (loading) {
    return <div />;
  }
  console.log(data);

  return (
    <div>
      <Layout>
        <Typography variant="h2" align="center">
          {data.sayHello}
        </Typography>
        <Link href="/about">
          <a>About</a>
        </Link>
        <div
          style={{
            display: "flex",
            flexWrap: "wrap",
            justifyContent: "center",
          }}
        >
          {items.map((item: any) => {
            return (
              <Card className={classes.card} key={item._id}>
                <CardActionArea>
                  <Link href={`/event/${item._id}`}>
                    <CardMedia
                      wide
                      className={classes.media}
                      image={item.image}
                      title={`${item.name} image`}
                    />
                  </Link>
                  <CardContent>
                    <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
                      {item.name}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography
                      variant="body2"
                      color="textSecondary"
                      component="p"
                    >
                      {`${item.description.substring(0, MAX_LENGTH)}...`}
                    </Typography>
                  </CardContent>
                </CardActionArea>
              </Card>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </Layout>
    </div>
  );
}

export default withApollo(Home);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by dynamically importing the `<Card>` component inside of the Home function:

```
 const Card = dynamic(() => import("@material-ui/core/Card"), {
    loading: () => <div>Loading...</div>,
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple reasons for this and because we cannot see the payload of the query, its hard to predict

Some areas to debug:
1. Is your response consistent

2. I compared your use to one of my project implementations and the only addition from my side was specifying `component={'img'}` within `CardMedia`
3. Additionally, instead of wrapping the code in `link` would it be possible to use cardActions API instead as suggested here - [How to make the whole Card component clickable in Material UI using React JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49007357/how-to-make-the-whole-card-component-clickable-in-material-ui-using-react-js)

Comment: Hey @Ramakay. I added `component={"img"}` as a property and the images appeared unformatted within the cards (all far too large with different sizes). 

I think the problem with adding `component={"img"}` is that it converts it from a background image to an actual image which means that the ratio aspect is not being created (or preserved) by `height: 0, paddingTop: "56.25%"` and the dimentions of the card are being altered by the default dimensions of the images.

Comment: Hey @Ramkay, I fixed the issue. Look at my edit in my original post ^